# Entity is not API Accessible

Tags: api, managed-package, insufficient-privileges

I found this error in the debug logs, when I access the managed package VF pages.

Initially I installed a Queue manager application from app exchange, where It worked fine for me in my personal developer edition but not in my Org's unlimited sandbox instance.when I try to access the managed package VF page as "System admin" it throws me insufficient privileges error

Can you please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: have you checked security setting for that vf page ?

Comment: Assign the licence to user accessing via api.

Comment: @Himanshu, I am using system admin profile and I verified that I have access to all the managed package VF pages and associated Apex classes. But when I run those VF pages I observed the Exception in debug logs : System.NoaccessException Entity is not api accessible

Comment: @NishantSinghPanwar  This managed package is free and I dont see a button like Manage Licences after installation.